# Is there a way to simply get a Discord server's icon using Bash?

Tags: bash, discord

Is it possible to get a Discord server's icon using the server's invite link or server ID using a bash script? I searched the docs [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/intro) but couldn't find what I'm looking for.

My goal is to create a bash script and when I run it like this it'll download that server's icon using curl or wget;

`./myScript <discord invite link/server ID>`

Example server invite: https://discord.com/invite/wow

Same server's ID: 113103747126747136

Thanks!

Comment: Please post your current attempts to solve the problem, so that we can see where you are stuck. BTW, do you mean [_favicon_](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_favicon.asp) when you say _logo/icon_?

Comment: I'm stuck at finding how to do this. I meant the server's icon as it's called in Discord's terminology, not favicon.

Comment: Would be way easier to test if you would post example server id and invite link and which icon you want to get exactly. https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#get-guild has icon and https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#get-guild-preview and then you can go to https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#image-formatting

Comment: @KamilCuk I'm not sure how to work with this. For instance I'm trying this but it's returning `401 Unauthorized`; `curl https://discord.com/api/guilds/113103747126747136/preview` (server ID is from my example in the question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the invite API.

```
url=https://discord.com/invite/wow
invite=$(basename "$url")
invitejson=$(curl "https://discord.com/api/invites/$invite")
servericon=$(<<<"$invitejson" jq -r '.guild.icon')
serverid=$(<<<"$invitejson" jq -r '.guild.id')
case "$servericon" in
   a_*) ext="gif" ;;
   *) ext="png" # ??
esac
wget "https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/$serverid/$servericon.$ext"
xdg-open "$servericon.gif"
```

Comment: It's not always a gif AFAIK.

Comment: Thank you! This works just fine. I think server icon includes an `a_` prefix if it's a gif like this; `"icon": "a_99f4e43f681c6889b07089c01ac33b03"` if it's not a gif then there won't be an `a_` prefix, it'll just display the id. Here's an example; https://discord.com/api/invites/KeGhzt4

Comment: Seems to be in docs at https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#image-formatting . Just add a logic for that `case $servericon in a_*) a gif ;; *) not a gif ;;; esac`